# Receive params values from check box in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a form_for helper in new view and some checkbox like below

```
<% checkboxs[counter] =   "subchecked" + counter.to_s %>
<%= check_box_tag(checkboxs[counter], 10) %>
```

Then How check I receive the params values that is 10 value in create action of controller?

Comment: Would it be possible to rephrase your question or provide more code? It's not totally clear what you're asking.

Comment: Try `params[:subchecked0]` where the `0` could be any integer you used

Answer (score 0):

There's [a pretty awesome RailsCast about checkboxes and form helpers.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes).  Generally speaking, you may need something like this in your controller:

```
    matches = params.select do |key,value|
        unless key.to_s.scan(/subchecked[0-9]/).empty?
           value == 10
        end
    end
    # matches should contain all the checkboxes that have 10 in them
    matches
```